# Python - queens on chess board, mistake in my program

Tags: python

The exercise reads that I should ask for co-ordinates of two queens on 8x8 board. Output should determine whether queens can attack each other or not. (Following rules of chess fyi)

Queen can attack in 8 directions so vertical and horizontal is easy to get out of the way. Then I use while loop for one possible diagonal direction by comparing if the first queen is "Higher" or "lower" and more to the left or right. However my output does not work.

Example input: First co-ordinates 3 3
               Second co-ordinates 5 7
The output should have been "no" however, it returned "yes".

Why does it fail to return correct output?

Thank you for your help :)

```
queen1_1, queen1_2 = raw_input("Position of the first queen:").split()
queen2_1, queen2_2 = raw_input("Position of the second queen:").split()

queen1_1 = int(queen1_1)        
queen1_2 = int(queen1_2)
queen2_1 = int(queen2_1)        
queen2_2 = int(queen2_2)

if queen1_1 == queen1_2:
    print "Yes"
elif queen1_2 == queen2_2:
    print "Yes"
elif queen1_1 > queen2_1 and queen1_2 > queen2_2:
    while queen1_1 > 1 and queen1_2 > 1: 
        queen1_1 -= 1
        queen1_2 -= 1
        if queen1_1 == queen2_1 and queen1_2 == queen2_2:
            print "Yes"
    else: 
        print "No"
elif queen1_1 < queen2_1 and queen1_2 > queen2_2:
    while queen1_1 < 8 and queen1_2 > 1: 
        queen1_1 += 1
        queen1_2 -= 1
        if queen1_1 == queen2_1 and queen1_2 == queen2_2:
            print "Yes"
    else: 
        print "No"
elif queen1_1 > queen2_1 and queen1_2 < queen2_2:
    while queen1_1 < 1 and queen1_2 < 8: 
        queen1_1 -= 1
        queen1_2 += 1
        if queen1_1 == queen2_1 and queen1_2 == queen2_2:
            print "Yes"
    else: 
        print "No"
elif queen1_1 < queen2_1 and queen1_2 < queen2_2:
    while queen1_1 < 8 and queen1_2 < 8: 
        queen1_1 += 1
        queen1_2 += 1
        if queen1_1 == queen2_1 and queen1_2 == queen2_2:
            print "Yes"
    else: 
        print "No"
```

Comment: Why not use `pdb` and see for yourself?

Comment: Would it not be better to check if the (absolute) difference in x-coordinate is equal to the (absolute) difference in y-coordinate to determine if two queens lie on the same diagonal?

Comment: You are right, I can't believe this solution did not come to my mind. Thank you, I've managed to make it work :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here:

```
if queen1_1 == queen1_2:
print "Yes"
```

You're checking the first queen's row against its column, rather than against the second queen's row.

Should be

```
if queen1_1 == queen2_1:
print "Yes"
```

Comment: I've managed to do it at last. I used solution suggested by @xnx